# Disabling service recycling in ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server

Is it possible to disable recycling for a service? I am using Server 10.6.1. I am thinking there is some hack to this because its clearly not an option using the Manager interface.

Comment: Well, it certainly *shouldn't* be possible.  Service recycling improves service and server reliability.  I tweak my service creation parameters to force staggering of recycle times (00:00, 00:20, 00:40,... 05:40, 00:10,... 05:50,...), to reduce the load of recycling on the Server instance, but I wouldn't for a second consider not recycling.

Comment: I agree. But I have a scheduled nightly restart for arcgis server, which we found to be more effective than individual services recycle. This makes recycling unnecessary, hence the need to disable.

Comment: I've never seen a benefit to a daily restart, though some clients implement a monthly restart or EC2 rebuild with 4-8 week interval application rebuilds. All my applications are 24x7 availability, but if you schedule stop and start 15 minutes apart around the recycle time, then recycle is moot.